# JS Regex get everything between two matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Was messing around on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and couldn't figure out how to do this. Given this pattern:

```
/u001b[35m
/u001b[38m
/u001b[67m
/u001b[92m
```

I know that `/u001b[` will always be the same and `m` will always be the same. I need to match anything that is enclosed by both, and have it return the whole string (`/u001b[67m`, for example).

Hey - I figured this out: don't know enough about regex to know if it will always work:

```
/\/u001b\[[0-9]*m/
```

Comment: What's wrong with my question? Is regex just bad news on SO?

Comment: @dc2: This looks like some sort of control character. Without saying how you got it in the first place, it looks like you are doing it wrong by matching them in this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\/u001b\[\d+m$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX5hZ3/1)

- `/` needs to be escaped in regex as it is used as regex delimiter.
- `[` is special meta-char hence needs to be escaped as well.

PS: If there can be anything (not just numbers) between start and end strings then use:

```
/^\/u001b\[.*?m$/gm
```

Comment: This works great, and +1 for the explanation and demo.